# Disable auto-maximation of windows in Gnome3

Tags: rhel, gnome, window

I have just upgraded my desktop system to RHEL 7, which comes with Gnome 3 as a window manager by default.

Irritatingly, whenever I drag a window to the top of the desktop, it automatically gets maximized as well, so I have to click the maximise button or drag it back down to get it to keep its size. I have looked both in Settings and in TweakUI, and I can't find any setting that seems to have with this to do.

How can I make Gnome stop maximizing my windows, preferably without having to change to another window manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings that control this are not available in the configuration dialogues. It has to be changed from the command line with `gsettings`, like so:

```
 $ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.classic-overrides edge-tiling false
```

After running this, the windows keep their size even when I move them to the top of the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

dconf equivalent (for turning off the edge-tiling "feature"):

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/classic-overrides/edge-tiling false
```